# understanding duplicity output - confusing file names

Tags: backup, duplicity

I scheduled a full backup, and inadvertently pointed to a directory (on an external drive) that held the previous duplicity backup.
The GUI tells me that it is creating a full backup, but the output files have a confusing name:
duplicity-full..volnnnn.difftar.gpg

From what I can understand from the documentation full and difftar seem to be mutually exclusive.
based on the speed and amount of disk being consumed, I suspect that it is in fact a diff backup.

Comment: where were you planning to point the current backup ?

Comment: To a new empty directory on the same external drive.

Comment: From what I know about duplicity it checks for differences with the last backup before doing a new backup so you don't need to worry, let it backup to the original location it will simply do its job.. Forget files make sure and yes its a diff backup type of backup. Hope this explains it.

Comment: please add a link to the documentation you referenced.

Comment: Looked at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto
http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/duplicity.1.html

Answer (score 3):

An except from the official [man page](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/duplicity.1.html):

```
Duplicity incrementally backs up files and folders into tar-format volumes 
encrypted with GnuPG and places them to a remote (or local) storage backend.
See chapter URL FORMAT for a list of all supported backends
and how to address them. Because duplicity uses librsync, incremental
backups are space efficient and only record the parts of files that have
changed since the last backup. 
Currently duplicity supports deleted files, full Unix permissions, 
uid/gid, directories, symbolic links, fifos, etc., but not hard links.
```

That is the reason you see those *tar* files and duplicity actually uses the **difference** between backups sessions to *determine what needs to be backed up*.

You don't have to back up to another folder as this would **re-run** the initial backup as though **your system** was never backed up or is the first time its being backed up.

**Note:** that the size of the backup ca get very large overtime and take up a lot of space on your external HDD.

Like the man page said the backup files are signed to prevent tampering **so unless your not planning to do a fresh backup as it seems in your case don't tamper with the backed up files**. It encrypts the files hence the *.gpg*

The files are stored as **.tar** files but when a change has been made by the file owner then durring backup a **.difftar** file will be made that only backs up changes to the original file(s). It creates files with the name **duplicity-full** and **duplicity-inc**, here the former was the original backup and the latter the *incremental* changes that have occurred since the original. It will then use a **patching** system to restore files. Like the man page says if you **remove a duplicity-full** then a restoration will not be possible.

To deal with the huge size of the backup over time I simply delete the original folder (*duplicity*), after I am sure of no interruptions with a fresh backup process. Then I run a fresh backup, please note this is my own style and preference when dealing with the huge backup size as my system is quite large.

References:

Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto

man: http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/duplicity.1.html